# How to create a new text file in php once a new day starts for a continuous running process

Tags: php

I am running a spider (continuous processes) where I am creating a error log file (errorlog.txt) when a error occurs.However once the new day starts ie after 12 am the errors are still written in the previous day file.

Eg: If i run the spider on 30 May,once the time is 12 am and any error occurs in the spider the errors are still written in the text file for 30 May.How can a new file be created once an error occurs and the next day has started ? Please help

Comment: How far have you got, what have you done already? Show us some code!

Comment: What is your error handler like? do you have code for it?

Answer (score 0):

Add the date to the log filename

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but maybe this answer will be helpful to someone

before writing to the report file , name it with date() function like this

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Istanbul'); // set to your time region
$report_file = "report".date("d-m-Y").".html";
```

then when you write in the file , use the $report_file as output

```
file_put_contents($report_file,'<div class="fancy"> your fancy report data here </div>',FILE_APPEND);
```

so that way each day your script will create daily report